# rails: link_to into another controller with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I make a link_to point to an action in another controller including parameters. I have an array of transactions that reference a product id. I'm trying to make each transaction link to it's product.

**controller**

```
def page
  @transactions = Transaction.all
end
```

**page**(haml)

```
- @transactions.each do |x|
  = link_to "Product", {controller: "product", action: "show", id: x.product_id}
```

**error**

```
No route matches {:controller=>"product", :action=>"show", :id=>38}
```

**rake routes**

```
product GET    /products/:id(.:format)     products#show
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax issue:

The controller of Product is ProductsController (notice the plural), so you should pass this hash to link_to:

```
{controller: "products", action: "show", id: x.product_id}
                     ^
```

Also make sure that `x.product_id` is present, if not it will raise an error "No routes matches { ... }".

---

An improvement in your coding style would be to use the path helpers generate following your routes:

```
link_to "Product", product_path(x.product_id)
```

This helpers has been generated via the `resources :products` in your routes.rb

For more informations about the Url Helpers: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers